# Hosting WCF in WAS(Web Garden) -> control WorkerProcess lifetime

Tags: .net, wcf, was, web-garden

I'm trying to host my WCF service in WAS but have been struggling for a few hours already to accomplish the following scenario:

There is a single client and many WCF 'servers'. Based on the address of the endpoint, the client requests(or some other parameter), a new worker process should be spawned to host the WCF service or the request should be sent to an already existing worker process(for that address/parameter).

I'm using named pipes(everything happens on the same machine).

So for example:

endpoint address - net.pipe://localhost/MyService/A -> WAS has to spawn a new Worker Process1

endpoint address - net.pipe://localhost/MyService/B -> WAS has to spawn a new Worker Process2

endpoint address - net.pipe://localhost/MyService/C -> WAS has to spawn a new Worker Process3

endpoint address - net.pipe://localhost/MyService/B -> WAS has to redirect the request to Worker Process2

What would be the easiest way to accomplish that?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this instead of just letting IIS spawn a new thread for each request like it does by default? What is this new worker process supposed to accomplish?

Comment: I agree.  This is attempting to toss already-provided functionality out and reinvent the wheel.

Comment: This is a requirement - each process will have to 'serve' a hardware device(and eventually interop with some COM components). It will be much safer to be in a separate process. This will also push up the memory limits that I would hit with single process and threads. I just thought I could use the WAS build in process management(automatic activation, health monitoring, recycling etc.)